# Default Express app with Compass gives ENOENT

Tags: node.js, express, compass-sass

Ubuntu 14.04
Node 0.10.25
Express 4.2.0

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
npm install -g express-generator
express -c compass test
cd test
npm install
npm start
```

*send request from browser*

```
GET / 200 12ms - 206b

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: spawn ENOENT
    at errnoException (child_process.js:988:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:779:34)
npm ERR! weird error 8
npm WARN This failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node"
npm WARN For further explanations, please read
/usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian

npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 9):

The solution is to

```
$ gem update --system
$ gem install compass
```

per the package docs
https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-compass

Comment: Wherever you are, if you're surrounded by some people, please get someone to hug you vigorously!

Comment: @Viground Thank you very much! After hours of failed attempts, finally a solution.
Btw another way to get compass is `sudo apt-get install ruby-compass`