# Express.js w/ Compass doesn't work with PM2

Tags: node.js, express, compass-sass, pm2, express-generator

I have used the `express-generator` to generate a project with compass stylesheet engine:

```
express --css compass app
```

The app as expected when I start using `npm start` (or `node ./bin/www`, fwiw).

However, when I use pm2 to run the app, as `pm2 start ./bin/www` the app runs and returns an html response, but the CSS fails when the browser requests it, the process dies and pm2 restarts it. This is behind an nginx which returns a 502 Bad Gateway.

These are the pm2 logs:

```
0|www      | GET /home 200 320.238 ms - 914
0|www      | Error: spawn compass ENOENT
0|www      |     at exports._errnoException (util.js:1050:11)
0|www      |     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:193:32)
0|www      |     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:367:16)
0|www      |     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
0|www      |     at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9)
PM2        | App [www] with id [0] and pid [6624], exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2        | Starting execution sequence in -fork mode- for app name:www id:0
PM2        | App name:www id:0 online
```

I can't find any info as to why this is happening, and why it's working with node, but not with pm2. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Compass is a native dependency that needs to be installed.

```
$ gem update --system
$ gem install compass
```

Otherwise, and I strongly advise, you should compile your compass style sheets, not only since the hit on the server is high and unnecessary.

Related: [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24977115/default-express-app-with-compass-gives-enoent).

Comment: Yeah, it is installed. I probably could have mentioned it specifically, but I did say that everything works as expected when run using `node bin/www` (this includes compass).

Comment: Yeah, but the rest stands. There are to many layers (processes) being run here and it's hard to reason about. You are running some script from node, withoin your node process within your pm2 processes. Statically compiling the stylesheets should be best here, since you can't really say which script is executing from where or with which, say, cwd, which ENOENT liekly points to.

Comment: Also when I check out your generation part, I am not even able to run it. No wonder because of the 2 year old dependency of compass.